# Particle tracking in colloids and uniformity in fractional part function

Tags: colloids

I don't know if its right place to ask this question since chemistry and programming both are involved.

I was working on particle tracking of series of pictures (.tiff) of colloids. And I was Using [trackpy](http://soft-matter.github.io/trackpy/v0.5.0/tutorial/walkthrough.html) in python.

The code gives me the position of particle to suppixel accuracy.
[image: code snippets]

There is another step involved is of checking the subpixel accuracy. In this method we check the uniformity in the decimal part of the position

> a quick way to check for subpixel accuracy is to check that the decimal part of the x and/or y positions are evenly distributed. Trackpy provides a convenience plotting function for this called subpx_bias

[image]

Mask size is more or less the diameter of particle.

**I am not getting how does evenly distribution of decimal part ensures that we are on the right track?
And how a dip shows that we are wrong somewhere?**

You can also refer to [Eric weeks](http://www.physics.emory.edu/faculty/weeks//idl/tracking.html) website. on this website it is briefly mentioned that

> One failure mode is if the length scale in feature is made too small, then all the x and y coords get 'rounded off' to the nearest pixel value. The above command plots a histogram of the fractional part of the x-coords of the image. The physically distributed positions should be random -- giving a flat histogram. If the histogram has two peaks (near 0 and 1), set the size parameter in 'feature' a little bigger, determine a new masscut, and repeat until everything is happy.

Comment: Suppose you generate uniformly distributed random real numbers between 2 and 3, having 3 decimal places. Then subtracting 2 from each one will give uniformly distributed (roughly flat histogram) decimal fractions between 0 and 1. But if you had simply rounded off the original numbers to integers, you would only get 2 and 3. So that test is just to make sure the “length scale” is not corrupting the data. Make sense?

Comment: But , then how does increasing of diameter (size parameter of feature) makes the histogram flat

Comment: If the mask size is too small, you are biasing toward integers: the particles are being sorted, as it were, into integer sizes. This is a quantization error or discretization error, With a larger mask size, you effectively “dither” the size estimation and reduce the quantization error. Kind of like adding a little white noise to dither the pixels and avoid the chunky quantization.

Comment: can you please write a answer, I am just a beginner and not so clear about mask size too

Comment: This is not really a chemistry question: it is an instrument behavior or statistics question. I have not done any particle tracking experiments. Maybe this question should be migrated (not cross-posted) at the signal processing stack exchange or the CV stack exchange.

Comment: This reads a little bit like the automated blob and cell counting in microbiology.  Maybe there already is a library about this in ImageJ / Fiji ([example](https://imagej.net/IJ_Blob)).  Because you aim to tackle the problem with Python, and it is kind of image processing, I *infer* from OpenCV's advertised use in ML [OpenCV SimpleBlobDetector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076889/how-to-use-opencv-simpleblobdetector) could be helpful.